# How to express logical or in regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

How to express logical or in regular expression in python?
Why `re.search("o"|"a","hallo")` and `re.search(("o"|"a"),"hallo")` is wrong?

```
>>> if(re.search("a","hallo")):print("ok")
...
ok
>>> if(re.search("o","hallo")):print("ok")
...
ok
>>> if(re.search("o"|"a","hallo")):print("ok")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
>>> if(re.search(("o"|"a"),"hallo")):print("ok")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You're reeaally having more of a python-syntax problem, but I guess you *talk* about regex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead do it as:

```
re.search(r"(o|a)","hallo")
```

The `""` should encompass the whole pattern.

You could also do:

```
re.search(r"[oa]","hallo")
```